# how can I deploy my silverlight 4 application

Tags: c#, deployment, silverlight-4.0

I have a basic Silverlight 4 project called "MySLApp" which has the associated MySLApp.Web project. (names changed for simplicity)

It compiles down into these files (in the silverlight project):

- AppManifest.xaml
- MySLApp.dll
- MySLApp.xap
- MySLAppTestPage.html

And the Web project builds into:

- Bin\MySLApp.Web.dll
- ClientBin\MySLApp.xap

What I also have in my Web project is a **.ASHX** file that serves up a generated image, which my Silverlight application calls out to as the URL of an image:

```
var uri = new Uri(@"http://localhost:1122/ImageServer.ashx", UriKind.Absolute);
var bi = new BitmapImage(uri);
TagImage.Source = bi;
```

My big question boils down to this:

How do I deploy my app to my IIS server? What files from where do I need to get it to work? Including the .ASHX url?

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Silverlight is a client-side technology - You don't "deploy" to a server. Should be pretty much as simple as copying the xap file (and related files) to
a folder accessible by the web server.

Comment: yes, but its the "and related files" part that im interested in, and how do I deploy my ASHX file to expose it as a URL?

Comment: Don't you just place it on the server's file structure? I mean, like an ASPX file? Restart IIS if it's not working.